# Layer's resizing when I copy a layer to a different document? I don't want this to happen.

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, resize

I am working on converting a large map into a booklet format.  I am making selections of 4 inches by 7 inches then copying them to make a new layer.  When I drag this new layer into a new document it is increasing in size.  How to I make the sizing consistent between layers?

Answer (score 1):

The documents have different PPI resolutions. If you want 4" x 7" to be the same on both documents than you need the PPI to also be the same. Photoshop doesn't copy inches it copies pixels.